# Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:984 - no such file to load -- poi

Tags: ruby

I am requiring the poi and getting below error on execution of file even though the poi is available in gems folder.

> Exception `LoadError' at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:984 - no such file
> to load -- poi

Answer (score 0):

I used the below command to install that specific gem poi and it worked.

gem install jruby-poi.

The gem was available in gemfile.lock but it was not showing in the gem list that is why i had to install gem specifically.